# NSManagedObject's hasChanges is true while changedValues is empty

Tags: ios, macos, core-data, nsnotificationcenter

I am trying to observe individual `NSManagedObject` changes on `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification`:

```
- (void)managedObjectContextWillSave:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    for (NSManagedObject * object in self.mutableObservedManagedObjects)
    {
        if (object.hasChanges)
        {
            [self managedObjectWasUpdated:object];
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that `hasChanges` is true while `object.changedValues` is empty, thus wrongly (?) triggering `managedObjectWasUpdated:`.

I'm trying to understand why this is the case and if I should better check `object.changedValues.count` before calling `managedObjectWasUpdated:`.

---

`isInserted` and `isDeleted` are both false.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I encountered the same issue. Instead of getting the flags, I just checked if changedValues() is empty.

For Swift:

```
if !managedObject.changedValues().isEmpty {
    // Has some changed values
}
```

Comment: That works, but still, this isn't documented behaviour and makes one wonder when Apple will break it... :(

Answer (score 13):

In my experience, if the entity already existed, you loaded it and then you set a value to a property that is equal to its previous value, then the record will be marked as updated, `hasChanges` will return `YES`, and `changedValues` will be empty. When you save the context, what gets updated is a special Core Data column called Z_OPT, which refers to the number of times an entity has been updated. For these situations you can do something like this before saving:

```
for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in context.updatedObjects.objectEnumerator) {
    if (!managedObject.changedValues.count) {
        [context refreshObject:managedObject mergeChanges:NO];
    }
}
```

in order to don't even update the Z_OPT value.

Comment: I believe this is the most accurate answer. `hasChanges` is based on _everything_ that Core Data knows about (including Z_OPT). `changedValues()` is reporting fields of your entity that are different.  In most cases applications probably care more about `changedValues().isEmpty`.

Comment: Instead of checking `changedValues.count` you can use a new property introduced on `NSManagedObject`: `var hasPersistentChangedValues: Bool`

Comment: Unfortunately `[NSManagedObjectContext -hasChanges]` still going to be `true`

Comment: Apparently changing a transient value also marks the object as being updated but with no changed values.

Answer (score 9):

From iOS 7 you can also use hasPersistentChangedValues instead of changedValues. I think this performs better.

Comment: Indeed `hasPersistentChangedValues` is the best choice. Based on header file's comment, `hasPersistentChangedValues` returns YES if any persistent properties do not compare `isEqual` to their last saved state.  Relationship faults will not be unnecessarily fired.  This differs from the existing `-hasChanges` method which is a simple dirty flag and also includes transient properties.

Answer (score 3):

According to doc, `hasChanges` will return YES if the receiver has been inserted, has been deleted, or has unsaved changes, otherwise NO.

In your case, you can check `isInserted`, `isUpdated`, `isDeleted` flag to find what happened to your managed object. `changedValues` only show the properties that have been changed since last fetching or saving the receiver.

Comment: I had followed the documentation and `isInserted`/`isDeleted` were both false, `isUpdated` true, yet no `changedValues`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any transient attributes on your entity? I am seeing the behavior you describe, and I've written some test code that shows that modifying a transient attribute causes `hasChanges` to return `true`, while `changedValues` is empty.

You can avoid this behavior by using `setPrimitiveValue:forKey:` to modify your transient attribute or the equivalent method generated by Core Data (`setPrimitiveFoo:` for an attribute named `foo`). You could also implement the transient attribute's setter to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

When another managed object in relationship to an NSManagedObject has changes, in my observation an NSManagedObject will *sometimes*, but not always, have an `isUpdated` of `true`, while `changedValues` is empty.

On other occasions, `isUpdated` is `false`, and again `changedValues` is empty.

`changedValues` being empty seems the correct behavior here. I am unclear what is cause of the variability in `isUpdated` being true. Having observed this in my production code, I am working on a simple sample project with hope of reproducing this for a bug report to Apple if I can.

To solve my functional problem in my case, I modified my code to automatically set a `timestampModified` on the parent object in cases where I wanted to ensure that `isUpdated` was always consistently set to `true` when these objects in relationship had changed.