# SwiftUI hasChanges always return true

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

My code is as follows。The **name** in the data is not changed，but **hasChanges** always returned **true** ，Did I do something wrong? Thank you very much for your help ！

```swift
struct SwiftUI: View {
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
  @Environment(\.presentationMode) var pre: Binding<PresentationMode>
  var data: CoreData
  @State private var name = ""

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      HStack {
        TextField("name", text: self.$name)
      }.onAppear{
        self.name = self.data.name ?? ""
      }

      Button(action: dataSave) {
        HStack {
          Text("Done")
        }
      }
    }
  }
  func dataSave() {
    self.data.name = self.name
    if moc.hasChanges {
      do {
        try moc.save()
        self.pre.wrappedValue.dismiss()
      } catch { print(error.localizedDescription) }
    } else {
      self.pre.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
  }
}
```

Why is it always returned true here?

```swift
moc.hasChanges
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSManagedObjectContext.hasChanges` is set to true when you assign to any attribute of an object in that context, even if the attribute's value is the same as it had before.

You can change your code to do:

```swift
    if self.name != self.data.name {
        self.data.name = self.name
    }
    if moc.hasChanges { /* ... */ }
```

or, check `hasPersistentChangedValues` on the object itself (not the context):

```swift
    self.data.name = self.name
    if self.data.hasPersistentChangedValues {
      do {
        try moc.save()
        self.pre.wrappedValue.dismiss()
      } catch { print(error.localizedDescription) }
    } else {
      self.pre.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
  }
```

Unfortunately `NSManagedObjectContext` does not have an equivalent `hasPersistentChangedValues` property. The second approach is only reasonable in your example and not the general case, where there could be many objects in the context that may have changed.

For more information on the behavior of `hasChanges` and `hasPersistentChangedValues` see this answer: [NSManagedObject's hasChanges is true while changedValues is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293852/nsmanagedobjects-haschanges-is-true-while-changedvalues-is-empty)

Comment: I see. It's settled. Thank you very much